# Is there any solved time-dependent solution for two-particle scattering?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, inertial-frames, scattering

I am looking for a time-dependent solution to the Schrödinger Equation for the scattering of two particles. I am only looking for a schematic idea of how the state evolves, and the potential may be any uniformly attractive or repulsive potential. I would expect the initial conditions to be gaussian-like but this is also open.

I have doubt in my mind whether this even has been done, but thought it would be worth asking here. To clarify, I'm not looking for a 1 particle solution in a potential, but a full two-particle (or more) solution to the TDSE.

Answer (score 0):

The quantum two-body problem reduces to the quantum "single-particle" problem in a fixed potential.  So once you've solved the quantum "single-particle" problem for a fixed potential, you can straightforwardly find the combined wavefunction for two interacting particles.  Here's how:

For a pair of interacting particles with positions $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_2$, the Hamiltonian will be
$$
H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_1} \nabla_1^2  - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m_1} \nabla_1^2 + V(\vec{r}_2 - \vec{r}_1)
$$
where $\vec{\nabla}_1$ is the gradient with respect to $\vec{r}_1$ and similarly for $\vec{\nabla}_2$.  This can
can be rewritten in terms of the center of mass position $\vec{R}$ and the particle separation vector $\vec{r}$ as
$$
H = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2M} \nabla_R^2  - \frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu} \nabla_r^2 + V(\vec{r})
$$
where $M = m_1 + m_2$, $\mu = m_1 m_2/M$, $\vec{\nabla}_R$ is the gradient with respect to $\vec{R}$, and $\vec{\nabla}_r$ is the gradient with respect to $\vec{r}$.

This latter Hamiltonian is separable, and corresponds to a free particle in $\vec{R}$ and a single particle in a "fixed potential" in $\vec{r}$.  So the combined time-dependent wave function for two particles reduces to the product of:

- a time-dependent wave function for a free particle in $\vec{R}$, and
- a time-dependent wave function for single particle scattering in the potential $V(\vec{r})$.

Once this is obtained, the combined wave function can be expressed in terms of the original particle positions by writing $\vec{R} = (m_1 \vec{r}_1 + m_2 \vec{r}_2)/M$ and $\vec{r} = \vec{r}_2 - \vec{r}_1$.

Note that this procedure is entirely analogous to the standard solution of the classical two-body problem, in which the problem is first split into the motion of the CM and the motion of the separation vector.

Comment: This is the standard procedure for the Hydrogen atom, it's a good point that it's useful for the time-dependent case; I had associated it with the time-independent. What remains at this point is to find a time-dependent solution to the single-particle Schrödinger equation with a gaussian initial condition in a Coulomb-like potential. That seems not very easy but I'm googling at the moment.

Comment: @doublefelix:  In principle, couldn't you decompose the initial Gaussian wavepacket into plane waves (via Fourier) and see how they evolve?  I'm pretty sure that the scattering of plane-wave solutions from a Coulomb potential is a solved problem.